# Visual Studio Bug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm encountered something weird, and I'm not sure if it's a bug in Visual Studio, or if maybe my ignorance is playing tricks on me.

I have two private class variables:

```
class MyClass
{
    private MyList<A> aList;
    private MyList<B> bList;
    [...]
```

And somewhere along the code, I'm using those variables for the first time.

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        object[] generatorOutput = Generator.Generate(args);
        aList = (MyList<A>)generatorOutput[0];
        bList = (MyList<B>)generatorOutput[1];
        [...]
```

Yet Visual Studio tells me, that bList is wrong:

```
Cannot use local variable 'bList' before it is declared.
The declaration of the local variable hides the Field 'MyNameSpace.MyClass.bList'.
```

I don't really understand what Visual Studio means. I **don't** want bList to be local, and it's **not** supposed to be hiding anything.

If it helps: bList was originally called cList and was a `MyList<C>` before I decided, that a `MyList<B>` was more than enough. The error message only appeared after renaming the variable and changing its type. The generatorOutput is always being casted into the correct type, by the way.

So, is this a bug, or am I missing something obvious?
I've already tried compiling the code, rewriting the line and even restarting Visual Studio without success...

Comment: can you show your actual code for `MyMethod`?

Comment: As it says in The Pragmatic Programmer (loosely quoted): "Never assume the fault is within the tool set you are using until you have ruled out all other reasons."

Comment: Is the error really pointing to the lines in MyMethod() ?

Comment: @Nolonar Have you executed a Clean for your solution and then, Rebuild?

Comment: @JasCav Someone should write a book explaining that Visual Studio _isn't the compiler_.

Comment: What are the classes and members *really* named?

Comment: Are you sure you don't define a local `bList` further down in your `MyMethod`?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - Haha...very good point indeed, sir.

Comment: Double-click on the second error. What line does it highlight?

Comment: @ JasCav & Mr.Disappointment: Does it really matter which does what? Visual Studio has a Parser, and I assume VS won't pass my code onto the Compiler, unless the Parser reports "no error", I could be wrong though. By the way, I found the answer already, thanks to everybody who tried to help.

Comment: @JasCav You're right, that's why I said [quote]I'm **not sure** if it's a bug in Visual Studio, or if maybe **my ignorance is playing tricks on me**.[/quote]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that your `MyMethod` continues like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    object[] generatorOutput = Generator.Generate(args);
    aList = (MyList<A>)generatorOutput[0];
    bList = (MyList<B>)generatorOutput[1];

    // ...

    var bList = new MyList<B>();  // <---
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew I had missed something obvious. I indeed had a local bList declared further below which I totally forgot about, when I renamed cList to bList.

Comment: @Nolonar: Clicking on the second error would have shown you that problem immediately. Is there a reason why you didn't investigate all compile errors?

Comment: I didn't find any "second error", Visual Studio only highlighted the first error and the Error Report only had 1 entry. This is especially frustrating given the fact, that the second error was right on the next line (It's stupid on my end, I know...)